# How do I change page orientation to landscape or portrait without affecting "page x of y" numbering?

Tags: numbering, microsoft-word-365, orientation, page

I have "page x of y" numbering. I'm using the `SECTIONPAGES` field code to tally the total number of pages for that section because I don't want it to count the title page.

I need to switch back and forth between portrait and landscape within that section or in a way that does not affect the total number of pages count. How to do that?

Comment: Which software ?

Comment: word 365, not enterprise

Comment: Use a page break before and after orientation change.

Comment: Portrait and landscape will fit different number of paragraphs.